# Where do I find basic syntax for Tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles

I'm working with text lines in a Tikz Header, and all I need is the options for anchor= (eg. anchor=north) and I can't find a basic list of anchor options anywhere

Comment: Try executing `texdoc tikz` from your terminal.

Answer (score 7):

The manual is the general reference. As Rowan Parkinson mentions in a comment, you can find it by issuing `texdoc tikz` from a terminal/command prompt. Or you can find the PDF on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [texdoc.net](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgf/0). There is also an HTML-version at https://tikz.dev/ (not created by the package maintainers).

However, as the manual covers a lot, it is quite large (1300 pages), and it can sometimes be hard to find stuff there. What you're after, the choices for `anchor`, is described in [**chapter 71 about the *Shape library***](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes) (which is in part V *Libraries*, if you look at the contents). Each different node shape may have differently named anchors, so for each shape described in that chapter, you'll find a diagram such as this one, naming the anchors and indicating where on the shape they are:

[image]