# How to place a node at the split using tikz rectangle split

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{pblock/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
                      rectangle split parts=3,
                      rectangle split part fill={red!30,blue!20,green!20}, draw, thick, align=center}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[pblock] (x) {\nodepart[text width=2cm]{one} Cell 1
                \nodepart[text width=4cm]{two}Cell 2
                \nodepart[text width=2cm]{three}Cell 3};
\node [above right=.6cm and 1.15cm of x.one south, anchor=base] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{/tikz/pblock/.append style = {every one node part/.style={text width=1cm}}}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following image:

[image: split-cell-image]

Notably, the `x` is placed using this line:

```
\node [above right=.6cm and 1.15cm of x.one south, anchor=base] {$x$};
```

As is obvious, this took some tinkering to get the exact right shift needed to get the `x` directly above the split between two rectangles. My question is how can I simply place the `x` above this boundary without needing to tinker with the placement? In general, I would want to place a `y` above the boundary between cell 2 and cell 3 as well.

Comment: `\node [above=.4cm of x.center, anchor=base] {$x$};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate of [Where do I find basic syntax for Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651638/where-do-i-find-basic-syntax-for-tikz/651648#651648) in a way, in that you just need to find the proper anchor. In this case:

```
\node [above=0pt of x.one split north] {$x$};
```

In general, a `rectangle split` node will have anchors called `<nodepart name> split <direction>`, for all but the last part. See the diagram in section *71.6 Shapes with Multiple Text Parts* in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

@Torbjørn T.'s excellent answer was very helpful especially with the [reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651638/where-do-i-find-basic-syntax-for-tikz/651648#651648). It turns out I need to place nodes not only above the splits, but on the ends as well. As a result, I've added the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name=s,pblock] (x) {\nodepart[text width=3cm]{one} Cell 1
                \nodepart[text width=4cm]{two}Cell 2
                \nodepart[text width=2cm]{three}Cell 3};
\draw[shift=(x.north west)] plot coordinates{(0,0)}
       node[above] {\scriptsize\texttt{$x_1$}};
\draw[shift=(x.one split north)] plot coordinates{(0,0)}
       node[above] {\scriptsize\texttt{$x_2$}};
\draw[shift=(x.two split north)] plot coordinates{(0,0)}
       node[above] {\scriptsize\texttt{$x_3$}};
\draw[shift=(x.north east)] plot coordinates{(0,0)}
       node[above] {\scriptsize\texttt{$x_4$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to produce

[image: split image]

This is slightly more complicated than the aforementioned answer, but if these anchors are needed it helps!